# How to disable window event capturing in Emscripten + SDL?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, sdl, emscripten

For my use case, I don't need any interaction between user and emscripten code through keyboard or mouse, I only need access to canvas.

I've noticed that Chrome puts many warnings on the console whenever I invoke code compiled with emscript, like

`Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.`

As I don't need any user interaction, I would like to disable these events to improve performance and avoid allocating unneeded objects.

I already set `doNotCaptureKeyboard` to true, is there a way to instruct emscripten to completely ignore all input DOM events?

Answer (score 0):

This is not well tested, but it seems to work:

```
<script>
    SDL.receiveEvent = function(event) {}
</script>
```

You can overwrite the main event function from SDL. Just make sure SDL is already loaded or put the code right before the closing body tag.

Keep in mind that you disable the entire event handling and this may cause issues. If you run into problems, you could try to rename the function and pass some events that you need.